# How to build SQL query that consolidate two tables?

Tags: sql

ALL

There are two tables, new and old.

```
[New] 
Machine Date 
A       Apr 16 
B       Apr 16 
A       Apr 15
C       Apr 15  
A       Apr 14 

[Old] 
Machine Date 
A       Apr 12 
B       Apr 10 
A       Apr 09 
C       Apr 08  
A       Apr 07
```

I want to bring Top 2 Machine where date > Apr 09

I can build a query for one table but dont know how to consolidate two table.

```
select top 2 machine, count(machine)
from new
where date > "Apr 09"
group by machine
```

it would be used two select query in one statement but don't know how to do.

Anyone can advise for this?

Answer (score 2):

If you'll be doing this often, I'd recommend creating a view that shows both tables:

```
CREATE VIEW AllData AS
SELECT * FROM [New]
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM [Old]
```

And then you can just select from the view and do whatever filtering you want:

```
select top 2 machine, count(machine)
from AllData
where date > "Apr 09"
group by machine
```

Also, I'm not sure if the data you're showing here is just an example, but I'd be careful about the date format you're using - since you're filtering based on a string, pretty much every date in the year will satisfy that condition, including "Jan 01". To update it, you may want to consider using an actual date type.

Comment: Thanks!! this is helpful for me to creat a query simply after making view!!

Answer (score 1):

The query that you seem to want is:

```
select top 2 machine, count(machine)
from ((select * from [New]
      ) union all
      (select * from [Old]
      )
     ) t
where date > "Apr 09"
group by machine
order by count(machine) desc
```

When you use `top`, you should always have an `order by`.  Otherwise, the results are indeterminate.  I am guessing that you want the two with the highest count.